# Providing settable global vars

Tags: clojure

I need to provide settable vars for my users, like *warn-on-reflection* provided by clojure AFAIK they are not defined on the clojure side thats why we can set them.

Problem is my vars (all configuration stuff) are used in a lot of tight loops thats why I don't want to make them refs cause they MAY get set when application starts up and thats it no change during runtime, they will be read maybe millions of times so making them refs seems like wasting resources.

So the question is can I define settable vars in my case?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a def?

Comment: I already use def, I need to change a deffed var

Comment: Have you considered using "binding"?

Comment: yes, forcing user to bind every configuration variable is not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*warn-on-reflection* is just a var, albeit one defined in Clojure's Java code rather than in core.clj.  However, aside from where it is defined, there is nothing special about *warn-on-reflection*; it behaves exactly like any other var.

If you do not want to use vars, you may need to approach your problem from a different perspective than "must use global variables".  It is common in functional programming to pass all necessary values into a function rather than relying on global variables.  Perhaps it is time for you to consider such an approach.

Comment: it is a built in var which means it is not defined in core.clj but in java code which means it is not defined in clojure.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding what you meant by "not defined in Clojure".  In any case, my main point is this: warn-on-reflection is a var, and aside from it being defined in Java code, it behaves just like any other var.  There is no concept of "vars with special powers".

Comment: it kinda is a special var in that you can set! it. when you define a var with say def you can not set! it but you can set! warn-on-reflection.

Comment: Currently, it is an error to attempt to set the root binding of a var using set!, i.e. var assignments are thread-local.  The Clojure java code defines *warn-on-reflection* with a thread binding.   Similarly, if you define your vars with "binding", you can use "set!".  There is no concept of "vars with special powers".

Answer (score 2):

If you want settable global state with low overhead that is visible to all threads and doesn't need any STM transactions to control mutation, I'd recommend just using atoms:

```
(def some-global-value (atom 1))
```

Reads and writes to atoms are *extremely* low overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create local binding using `let`, this way the parameters can be dynamic and you'll still have fast access. The only thing is that if someone change a parameter while the loop is running, the loop won't pick that up (IMO this should be the desired behaviour anyway).

Comment: let would only work for code that is in the let block, I am looking for something along the line of warn-on-reflection when set it would effect the whole library not just one block of code.